# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Inject')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I am using the syncfusion library to create a doc editor using Reactjs as a frontend framework. I have encountered an error while going through the documentation of the library

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/document-editor/scrolling-zooming/#zoom-option-using-ui

1. I created a react application using creat-react-app
2. I copy pasted the code from the above documentation link into my index.js file
3. There are no compile time errors but upon opening the website I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Inject')" error displayed in the console of the browser

My code:

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as React from "react";
import {
  DocumentEditorComponent,
  Print,
  SfdtExport,
  WordExport,
  TextExport,
  Selection,
  Search,
  Editor,
  ImageResizer,
  EditorHistory,
  ContextMenu,
  OptionsPane,
  HyperlinkDialog,
  TableDialog,
  BookmarkDialog,
  TableOfContentsDialog,
  PageSetupDialog,
  StyleDialog,
  ListDialog,
  ParagraphDialog,
  BulletsAndNumberingDialog,
  FontDialog,
  TablePropertiesDialog,
  BordersAndShadingDialog,
  TableOptionsDialog,
  CellOptionsDialog,
  StylesDialog,
} from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-documenteditor";
import { DropDownButtonComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-splitbuttons";
//Inject require module.
DocumentEditorComponent.Inject(
  Print,
  SfdtExport,
  WordExport,
  TextExport,
  Selection,
  Search,
  Editor,
  ImageResizer,
  EditorHistory,
  ContextMenu,
  OptionsPane,
  HyperlinkDialog,
  TableDialog,
  BookmarkDialog,
  TableOfContentsDialog,
  PageSetupDialog,
  StyleDialog,
  ListDialog,
  ParagraphDialog,
  BulletsAndNumberingDialog,
  FontDialog,
  TablePropertiesDialog,
  BordersAndShadingDialog,
  TableOptionsDialog,
  CellOptionsDialog,
  StylesDialog
);
export class Default extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.startPage = 1;
    this.items = [
      {
        text: "200%",
      },
      {
        text: "175%",
      },
      {
        text: "150%",
      },
      {
        text: "125%",
      },
      {
        text: "100%",
      },
      {
        text: "75%",
      },
      {
        text: "50%",
      },
      {
        text: "25%",
      },
      {
        separator: true,
      },
      {
        text: "Fit one page",
      },
      {
        text: "Fit page width",
      },
    ];
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let instance = this;
    instance.pageCount = document.getElementById("documenteditor_pagecount");
    instance.editablePageNumber = document.getElementById("editablePageNumber");
    instance.pageNumberLabel = document.getElementById(
      "documenteditor_page_no"
    );
    instance.updatePageCount();
    instance.updatePageNumber();
    instance.documenteditor.viewChange = function (e) {
      instance.updatePageNumberOnViewChange(e);
    };
    instance.documenteditor.contentChange = function () {
      instance.updatePageCount();
    };
    instance.editablePageNumber.onclick = function () {
      instance.updateDocumentEditorPageNumber();
    };
    instance.editablePageNumber.onkeydown = function (e) {
      instance.onKeyDown(e);
    };
    instance.editablePageNumber.onblur = function () {
      instance.onBlur();
    };
  }
  updatePageNumberOnViewChange(args) {
    if (
      this.documenteditor.selection &&
      this.documenteditor.selection.startPage >= args.startPage &&
      this.documenteditor.selection.startPage <= args.endPage
    ) {
      this.startPage = this.documenteditor.selection.startPage;
    } else {
      this.startPage = args.startPage;
    }
    this.updatePageNumber();
  }
  onBlur() {
    if (
      this.editablePageNumber.textContent === "" ||
      parseInt(this.editablePageNumber.textContent, 0) > this.editorPageCount
    ) {
      this.updatePageNumber();
    }
    this.editablePageNumber.contentEditable = "false";
  }
  onKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var pageNumber = parseInt(this.editablePageNumber.textContent, 0);
      if (pageNumber > this.editorPageCount) {
        this.updatePageNumber();
      } else {
        if (this.documenteditor.selection) {
          this.documenteditor.selection.goToPage(
            parseInt(this.editablePageNumber.textContent, 0)
          );
        } else {
          this.documenteditor.scrollToPage(
            parseInt(this.editablePageNumber.textContent, 0)
          );
        }
      }
      this.editablePageNumber.contentEditable = "false";
      if (this.editablePageNumber.textContent === "") {
        this.updatePageNumber();
      }
    }
    if (e.which > 64) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  onZoom(args) {
    this.setZoomValue(args.item.text);
    this.updateZoomContent();
  }
  setZoomValue(text) {
    if (text.match("Fit one page")) {
      this.documenteditor.fitPage("FitOnePage");
    } else if (text.match("Fit page width")) {
      this.documenteditor.fitPage("FitPageWidth");
    } else {
      this.documenteditor.zoomFactor = parseInt(text, 0) / 100;
    }
  }
  updateZoomContent() {
    this.zoom.content = Math.round(this.documenteditor.zoomFactor * 100) + "%";
  }
  updatePageNumber() {
    this.pageNumberLabel.textContent = this.startPage.toString();
  }
  updatePageCount() {
    this.editorPageCount = this.documenteditor.pageCount;
    this.pageCount.textContent = this.editorPageCount.toString();
  }
  updateDocumentEditorPageNumber() {
    let editPageNumber = document.getElementById("editablePageNumber");
    editPageNumber.contentEditable = "true";
    editPageNumber.focus();
    window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(editPageNumber);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DocumentEditorComponent
          id="container"
          height={"330px"}
          ref={(scope) => {
            this.documenteditor = scope;
          }}
          isReadOnly={false}
          enablePrint={true}
          enableSelection={true}
          enableEditor={true}
          enableEditorHistory={true}
          enableContextMenu={true}
          enableSearch={true}
          enableOptionsPane={true}
          enableBookmarkDialog={true}
          enableBordersAndShadingDialog={true}
          enableFontDialog={true}
          enableTableDialog={true}
          enableParagraphDialog={true}
          enableHyperlinkDialog={true}
          enableImageResizer={true}
          enableListDialog={true}
          enablePageSetupDialog={true}
          enableSfdtExport={true}
          enableStyleDialog={true}
          enableTableOfContentsDialog={true}
          enableTableOptionsDialog={true}
          enableTablePropertiesDialog={true}
          enableTextExport={true}
          enableWordExport={true}
        />
        <div id="page-fit-type-div">
          <label id="page"> Page </label>
          <div id="editablePageNumber">
            <label id="documenteditor_page_no" />
          </div>
          <label id="of">of</label>
          <label id="documenteditor_pagecount" />
          <DropDownButtonComponent
            ref={(scope) => {
              this.zoom = scope;
            }}
            items={this.items}
            cssClass="e-de-statusbar-zoom"
            select={this.onZoom.bind(this)}
          >
            {" "}
            100%{" "}
          </DropDownButtonComponent>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Default />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

How can I solve this?

Is there a better way to create a doc editor using react?

Comment: that implies that `DocumentEditorComponent` is undefined ... is it? (console.log will help you decide) .. i.e. does `@syncfusion/ej2-react-documenteditor` export that?

Comment: @Bravo not Null, undefined. thats a difference but your hint is the correct way

Comment: yeah, I noticed :p

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact the vendor. Your code for importing `DocumentEditorComponent` and calling `Inject` on it matches the example you linked, so that suggests some problem with the example or you're using a different version of the library than the example is.